# Triangle on the bottom border of an element

Tags: html, css, css-shapes

What I'm trying to do is to create a triangle on the bottom border of a block with CSS, and write some text in there like it's shown in this figure :

[image: tirangle on the bottom border]

What I did so far, is :

1. Create the block element, with its its orange big bottom border.
2. Create the triangle using CSS.

All I need now is a way to place that triangle exactly in the middle of that exact place. I tried several ways to do that, but without any result.

Here's my [code](https://jsfiddle.net/yod8Lvjt/) :

```css
.content_block {
  position: relative;
  border: ridge;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-color: #969696;
  background: #FFF;
}
.content_block.orange {
  border-bottom: 40px solid #F59A3C;
}
.content_block > .image {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  height: 110px;
  width: auto;
  top: 20%;
  left: 15%;
}
.content_block > .text {
  position: absolute;
  color: #FFF;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 12pt;
  top: 105%;
  left: 33%;
}
.content_block.size_3 {
  height: 207px;
  width: 240px;
}
.content_block.triangle {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 25px 0 0 25px;
  border-color: transparent transparent transparent #FE992C;
}
```

```html
<div class="content_block orange size_3">
  <img src="http://upload.dinhosting.fr/c/D/B/demenage.PNG" class="image">
  <div class="text">Je déménage</div>
</div>
```

You can notice that there's an HTML class called triangle that I don't show. I don't know how to show it exactly in that position.

EDIT : 
I'm using the exact selector ( .content_block ) for showing other blocks; Like this block for instance :

[image]

So, a solution with after pseudo element will affect this block too. This is why I really need to avoid pseudo elements..

Comment: It doesn't work.
EDIT:  I will see see that now.

Comment: You also need to add <div class="triangle"></div> in your html.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Edit

If you can't use a pseudo element for the triangle, you will need to add an element. You can add it as a child of the `.content_block` element. This uses the same approach described in the original answer :

```css
.content_block {
  position: relative;
  border: ridge;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-color: #969696;
  background: #FFF;
}
.content_block.orange {
  border-bottom: 40px solid #F59A3C;
}
.content_block > .image {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  height: 110px;
  width: auto;
  top: 20%;
  left: 15%;
}
.content_block > .text {
  position: absolute;
  color: #FFF;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 12pt;
  top: 105%;
  left: 33%;
}
.triangle {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 50%;
  border-right: 20px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 12px solid #F59A3C;
}
.content_block.size_3 {
  height: 207px;
  width: 240px;
}
```

```html
<div class="content_block orange size_3">
  <img src="http://upload.dinhosting.fr/c/D/B/demenage.PNG" class="image">
  <div class="triangle"></div>
  <div class="text">Je déménage</div>
</div>
```

### Original answer:

You can make the triangle with the [border technique](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7073484/1811992) and a pseudo element.

In the following example, I used the `.content_block:after` pseudo element with absolute positioning:

```css
.content_block {
  position: relative;
  border: ridge;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-color: #969696;
  background: #FFF;
}
.content_block.orange {
  border-bottom: 40px solid #F59A3C;
}
.content_block > .image {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  height: 110px;
  width: auto;
  top: 20%;
  left: 15%;
}
.content_block > .text {
  position: absolute;
  color: #FFF;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 12pt;
  top: 105%;
  left: 33%;
}
.content_block:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 50%;
  border-right: 20px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 12px solid #F59A3C;
}
.content_block.size_3 {
  height: 207px;
  width: 240px;
}
```

```html
<div class="content_block orange size_3">
  <img src="http://upload.dinhosting.fr/c/D/B/demenage.PNG" class="image">
  <div class="text">Je déménage</div>
</div>
```

Comment: What happens if I'm already using the after pseudo element for something else ? (Something that I was planning to do).

Is it the only way of doing that ?

Comment: @Humoussama if you aren't using the before pseudo element, you can use that one instead.

Comment: Yes I know. 

But is there any other solution that don't use the pseudo elements ?
I would like to keep the pseudo elements for some special effects.

Comment: @Humoussama ok, you can also use the pseudo elements of the `.text` element but if they are also used, you will need to add another element (child of `.content_block`) to make the triangle.

Comment: Still, like I told you, there's a problem, that I will explain more by editing my  post.

Comment: I edited my post. You can see the problem that I will have for instance by doing that with pseudo elements

Comment: @Humoussama I edited the answer using a sperate element for the triangle.

Answer (score 1):

User `:after` selector and position that `absolutely`
Here is updated fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/yod8Lvjt/1/